# iOS, 'NSInvalidArgumentException' on NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have data coming in from a JSON source.

The value of key hour is an integer:

```
{"busy": {"day":"monday", "month":"February", "hour":20}}
```

Here i make use of the values

```
NSString *hour = [[self.stats valueForKey:@"busy"] valueForKey:@"hour"];
NSString *day = [[self.stats valueForKey:@"busy"] valueForKey:@"day"];
NSString *month = [[self.stats valueForKey:@"busy"] valueForKey:@"month"];

NSLog(@"hour: %@", hour);
NSLog(@"day: %@", day);
NSLog(@"month: %@", month);

self.busyHour.text = (NSString *)hour;
self.busyDay.text = day;
self.busyMonth.text = month;
```

I get the correct output from the NSLogs of all 3 of the values, yet when i attempt to assign `self.busyHour.text` i get the following error.

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000093
2015-02-16 10:30:41.133 changeView[1494:411656] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger hour = [[[self.stats valueForKey:@"busy"] valueForKey:@"hour"] integerValue];
self.busyHour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hour];
```

Comment: ah, i had tried intValue & forgot about integerValue

Answer (score 0):

This is really self explanatory... you're assigning `hour` to `self.busyHour` and you're casting it - did you check it's really an `NSString` before doing so?